# C# Foreach Usage

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to use 2 variables and iterate over different objects with a single line foreach,
If I wanted to do it with python I could use as follows.

```
<div>
        @(for firstSong, secondSong Model.Web.OrderBy(p=>p.ListOrder()) )
        {
        <div class="item">
           <div class="row">
              firstSong.Name
           </div>
           <div class="row2">
              secondSong.Name
           </div>
        </div>
        }
        </div>

    <div>
```

but I want to do the same thing with c#, how can I do it?

```
@foreach(var song in Model.Web.OrderBy(p=>p.ListOrder())
{
<div class="item">
   <div class="row">
      song.Name
   </div>
   <div class="row2">
      song.Name
   </div>
</div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly does `for i, j` mean? Without understanding the Python syntax, it's a little confusing to me where this second value is coming from. Can you explain what it does, perhaps with an example?

Comment: Are the variables related? Where are they coming from?

Comment: I updated the code. i mean i want to get 2 objects in a single foreach loop.

Comment: So you want a way to get two items from `Model.Web` at a time?

Comment: _"i want to get 2 objects in a single foreach loop."_ - do you mean a single foreach loop _iteration_? As you will get all objects in a single loop, but only one at a time in an iteration.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar
So you want a way to get two items from Model.Web at a time? 

Yes i want that

Comment: What type is `Model.Web`? For the python version above to work it'd need to contain tuples, is that also the caser for the c# version?

Comment: @AndrewSkirrow - Generic List

Comment: @TheAsh, of what -- you're python example iterates a list of tuples, it's not clear what type of pair you're iterating

Comment: I just want to get two models in a single loop.

Comment: OK. Well you're python code doesn't do that either

Comment: i just said it as an example yes you are right

Comment: No, you can't and I doubt python or whatever other languaje implements a for loop that way

Comment: Final question. What happens if there are an odd number of items in the list?

Comment: @AndrewSkirrow then only one item is listed.That's okay, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4):

In older C# you'd possibly do this with a plain `for` that jumps 2:

```
var arr = Model.Web.OrderBy(p=>p.ListOrder()).ToArray();
@for(int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x+=2)
{
<div class="item">
   <div class="row">
      @arr[x].Name
   </div>
   @if(x+1 < arr.Length){
     <div class="row2">
      @arr[x+1].Name
     </div>
   }
</div>
}
</div>
```

You could use some LINQ to juggle your collection into tuples of song pairs, if your C# is modern enough to have Chunk (.net6+)

```
@foreach(var array in Model.Web.OrderBy(p=>p.ListOrder()).Chunk(2))
{
<div class="item">
   <div class="row">
      @array[0].Name
   </div>
   @if(arr.Length > 1){
     <div class="row2">
      @array[1].Name
     </div>
   }
</div>
}
</div>
```

There are other ways of doing it in older LINQ, such as projecting to include the index of each item, using a Where to take only the evens and Zipping them together with only the odds, or grouping them by the divide-by-2 of the index, but it gets a bit ugly:

```
@foreach(var array in Model.Web.OrderBy(p=>p.ListOrder()).Select((o,i)=>new{o,i}).GroupBy(at => at.i/2, at=> at.o), (k,g)=>g.ToArray())
...
    <div class="item">
       <div class="row">
          @array[0].Name
       </div>
       @if(array.Length > 1){
         <div class="row2">
          @array[1].Name
         </div>
       }
    </div>
```

It'd perhaps be better to write your own Chunk/lift it from [the .net source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Chunk.cs)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using .NET 6 and can't take advantage of `.Chunk` (as in the other answer), you could perhaps get an `IEnumerator<Song>` and iterate through that manually:

```cs
@{
    IEnumerator<Song> songEnumerator = Model.Web.OrderBy(p => p.ListOrder()).GetEnumerator();
    while (songEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        <div class="item">
            <!-- handle the first song -->
            <div class="row">
                @songEnumerator.Current.Name
            </div>

            <!-- try and get the second item -->
            @if (@songEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                <div class="row2">
                    @songEnumerator.Current.Name
                </div>
            }

        </div>
    }
}
```